# How to set F# 4.0 in Visual Studio?

Tags: f#

I've just installed F# 4.0 (FSharpBundle). How to let visual studio 2013 use the new version of F#?

```
// From Visual Studio 2013, fsi:
Microsoft (R) F# Interactive version 12.0.30815.0
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All Rights Reserved.

For help type #help;;

>
```

The new version from powershell:

```
// PS C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\F#\4.0\Framework\v4.0> .\Fsi.exe

Microsoft (R) F# Interactive version 14.0.22312.0           
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All Rights Reserved.   

For help type #help;;                                       

>
```

Comment: It looks like it is only supported in VS2015. I was never able to open a v4.0 project in VS2013, project properties page just doesn't recognize the version 4. This article also mentions VS2015 only: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2015/04/29/rounding-out-visual-f-4-0-in-vs-2015-rc.aspx

Comment: @V.B. Thank you! The link is also helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

F# 4.0 is only supported in VS 2015, which is still pre-release.

You can download the RC build (latest public build) [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/visual-studio-2015-downloads-vs.aspx).  This comes with fairly new F# stuff, and you can install the latest dev builds from https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/releases on top of it.

In theory if you build from [source](https://github.com/microsoft/visualfsharp) using the VS 12.0 toolchain you can still run private F# 4.0 bits in VS 2013.

Comment: Now that VS 2015 has been released, does this answer still hold true? I can't use F# 4.0 in 2013 still?

Comment: For future visitors, F# 4.0 requires VS2015 installed, as it depends on Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core v14